# Qt - Split and use string from lineEdit as regExp

Tags: qt, qstring, qtcore, qregexp

I want to filter all my data by typing a string, sounds simple. 
This is what I got so far:

```
stringToSearch.replace( QRegExp(" "), "|" );

QRegExp regExp(stringToSearch,Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::Wildcard); 

model->removeRows(0,model->rowCount());
for(int row = 0; row < stringsInTable.filter(regExp).count(); row++)
{
    model->appendRow(new QStandardItem(QString(stringsInTable.filter(regExp).at(row))));
}
```

This works fine if I just search for one word or if I search with '*' between the words if they come in correct order that is.
But how can I search for multiple words and the order of the words should not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Positive Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) feature and build your regexp string using all words entered. Here's a quick example (let's suppose input `one two three`):

```
QRegExp re("^(?=.*one)(?=.*two)(?=.*three).*$");
qDebug() << re.exactMatch("two three one four"); // returns true
```